# How to change background color of tool window in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

How to change background color of tool window in Android Studio?

Is it possible to change the tool window background from white to gray?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello by going throught below path you can change your background color :-

**EDITOR-> COLORS AND FONTS-> CONSOLE COLORS**

[image]

Comment: It's for changing background color of consols not tool windows. Tried this before and must say I don't use dark themes as you show in this image.

Comment: I changed text color of 'git added' files in  'Project' window  using the EDITOR-> COLORS AND FONTS-> FILE STATUS ->modifyed. You need to apply changes and reopen 'Project' window